# how to redirect users to a page after login only when a specific menu item is clicked?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a link "Add a Post" (url: /node/add/mypost) which is not directly accessible to users.

I want to display a menu item titled "Add a Post" so that when users click on it, user goes to login page and THEN goes to "/node/add/post"

I have tried using "logintoboggan" and "rules" modules but these redirect user to "node/add/mypost" EVERYTIME a user logs in - I also have a "log in" only link where I just want the user to come back to home page after logging in.

Question Summary: How to have redirect users to a node add form based on a menu item that they clicked on? (menu item here = separate than the "log in" link)

Comment: Does [this](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the link like this:

```
user/login?destination=node/add/post
```

after login they'll be sent to the add post form.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much! 
One note for other folks who may try this... In the link for the menu item, I had to enter the entire URL. What I mean: I had to enter "www.example.com/user/login?destination=node/add/post', just adding "user/login?destination=node/add/post" did not work.

Comment: Great - you're welcome. Yeah if it's a menu item the relative url wouldn't work without adding a menu callback to a custom module I think - adding the absolute url is easier for a quick fix.